# Subquery in a Trigger at ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

Hi i want to do a subquery in a trigger

like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER verificar_edad

BEFORE INSERT ON reserva

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

BEGIN

IF (:new.pasaporte_cliente in (SELECT pasaporte FROM cliente WHERE fecha_nacimiento>'1996/01/01')) THEN

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('El cliente debe ser mayor de edad');

 END IF;

END;
```

/

but it does not works... What am I supposed to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you want to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in a trigger unless your 'application' consists of typing commands in SQL*Plus or Toad. If you mean to disallow the insert and tell the client why, then instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE:

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'El cliente debe ser mayor de edad');
```

Codes less than -20999 and -20000 are reserved for developer-defined errors

Your logic looks less like a check of the client's age than a check whether the client has a record in the passport ('pasaporte') table.

For a validation that requires a SQL SELECT, where the point is to verify that the client is over 18 years of age, it would go something like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_verified number;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into v_verified  
    FROM cliente 
   WHERE fecha_nacimiento > (sysdate - (365*18)) -- or more sophisticated function that accounts for leap years
     and pasaporte = :new.pasaporte_cliente;
  IF v_verified = 0 then 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20010, 'El cliente debe ser mayor de edad');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, still climbing the learning curve for formatting on this venue.

Comment: For future reference: in the editor, the button with the Java-esque brackets `{}` applies code-format to highlighted text.